# calling a function from another plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having problem with calling a function from another plugin it seems to return nothing tho this does work on other plugin

```
function caller_func()
{
if (!function_exists('form')) return;
return form($number = null);
}

function chrp1_get_popup(){

    $chrp1_popup = '<div id="fullscre"></div>';

    $chrp1__query= "post_type=popup-widget-details&showposts=1";

    query_posts($chrp1__query);

    if (have_posts())  : the_post();

    $chrp1_mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('code');

    $chrp1_descrip = get_the_content();

    $chrp1_popup .= '<span onclick="chrp1_showall();">'.$chrp1_descrip.'</span>';

    $chrp1_popup .= '<div id="newsox">';

    $chrp1_popup .= '<img src="'.chrp1_PATH.'image/cross.png" class="ccross" 
    onclick="chrp1_getrid();" width="23"/>';

    $getfunc = 'caller_func';
    $chrp1_popup .=  $getfunc();

    $chrp1_popup .= '</div>';



    endif; wp_reset_query();         

return $chrp1_popup;

}
```

this code works on my other plugins I want to call but not this one below can anybody help

```
function form($number = null) {
    if ($number == null)
        return $this->subscription_form();
    $options = get_option('newsletter_forms');

    $form = $options['form_' . $number];

    if (stripos($form, '<form') !== false) {
        $form = str_replace('{newsletter_url}', plugins_url('newsletter/do/subscribe.php'), $form);
    } else {
        $form = '<form method="post" action="' . plugins_url('newsletter/do/subscribe.php') . '" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)">' .
                $form . '</form>';
    }

    $form = $this->replace_lists($form);

    return $form;
}
```

when I check the source code nothing from the form has loaded

Comment: In `form` function is used `$this` - that seems odd.

Comment: the function I am trying to call is not my function or plugin

Comment: Try enable DEBUG option in wp-config.php - that should show you any errors.